# Can $\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}$be written as a function of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I started by noticing that the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is always between $1$ and $-1$. Therefore if i have a line that intersects the $x$ axis at $45°$ it will aways pass through the line once or be tangent to it. In other words  $\sin(x)=\pm x-a$ has only one solution for any $a$ and sign for $x$. So using the rotation matrix to rotate $\sin(x)$ $-45°$ around the origin I get
 $$\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{2}}$$ 
I got stuck on trying to write this as a function of $x$ but i do believe it can be. And as an add on question can the same be done for $\sin(x+y)=y-x$

Comment: if you have an program you can use implicitplot

Comment: I have the plot up on demos and its a cool looking graph, like curvy stairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one way to approach this is to use the power series expansion around the origin of $$sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}- \cdots$$
A first approximation would then be $sin(x+y)=x+y-\frac{(x+y)^3}{3!}=y-x$, which yields $y=-x+\sqrt[3]{12x}$. This provides a nice plot (Desmos):

[image]

You could take more powers of the in the Taylor-expansion into account of course.

Comment: This is a cool approach and quickly reach better and better appoximation of a function of x (I've noticed that it can only be expressed like that in even terms otherwise y has multiple values) The issue is that you very quickly get very hard to solve polynomials. Would you know any way aronnd that ?

Comment: You are right, for higher powers, it becomes difficult: this amounts to making $y$ explicit in the equation $(x+y)^5-20(x+y)^4+240x=0$. I tried to work with approximations of $(x+y)^k=x^k+ky$ when $y$ is very small. But this leads to functions that are not at all a good approximation of the original one.